# React Component not rerendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, react-hooks, flux

I am using flux and for some reason when adding a new Todo, the component is not rerendering. When clicking delete or changing the checkbox it is though. What is causing this? The actual list is rendering in another component but it has no logic. If you need more to answer it, you can see my code here, http://github.com/lukeshay/react_spring_web_app. It is on "fix-todo-page-update" branch.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import TodoList from "./TodoList";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import todoStore from "../../stores/todoStore";
import { loadTodos, saveTodo, deleteTodo } from "../../actions/todoActions";
import { toast } from "react-toastify";

function TodoPage() {
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    const [adding, setAdding] = useState(false);
    const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);
    const [newTodo, setNewTodo] = useState({
        text: "",
        completed: false
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        todoStore.addChangeListener(onChange);
        if (todoStore.getTodos().length === 0) {
            loadTodos();
            setLoading(false);
        }
        return () => todoStore.removeChangeListener(onChange);
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(newTodo);

        if (!adding && newTodo.text !== "") {
            saveTodo(newTodo);
            toast.success("Todo saved.");
        }

        setNewTodo({
            text: "",
            completed: false
        });
    }, [adding]);

    async function onChange() {
        setTodos(todoStore.getTodos());
    }

    async function onCheckboxChange({ target }) {
        console.log(target.name);

        var todoToUpdate = todos.find(
            todo => todo.id === parseInt(target.name)
        );
        todoToUpdate.completed = !todoToUpdate.completed;
        saveTodo(todoToUpdate);
    }

    async function onDeleteButtonClick({ target }) {
        deleteTodo(target.name);
    }

    async function onAddClick() {
        setAdding(!adding);
    }

    async function onInputChange({ target }) {
        const { value } = target;
        setNewTodo({ ...newTodo, text: value });
    }

    async function handleKeyPress({ target, key }) {
        if (key === "Enter" && target.name === "newTodo") {
            setAdding(false);
        }
    }

    if (loading) {
        return <h1>Loading...</h1>;
    } else {
        return (
            <div className="col-lg-12">
                <div className="card px-3">
                    <div className="card-body">
                        <h4 className="card-title text-center">Todo list</h4>
                        <TodoList
                            todos={todos}
                            onCheckboxChange={onCheckboxChange}
                            onDeleteButtonClick={onDeleteButtonClick}
                        />
                        {adding && (
                            <input
                                type="text"
                                name="newTodo"
                                value={newTodo.text}
                                onChange={onInputChange}
                                onKeyPress={handleKeyPress}
                            />
                        )}

                        <button className="" name="add" onClick={onAddClick}>
                            Add Todo
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default TodoPage;
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that something is going wrong with the server request which I didn't test. I modified your `saveTodo` action like following and got the new Todo element rendered:

```js
export async function saveTodo(todo) {
    const savedTodo = todo;//await todoApi.saveTodo(todo);
    dispatcher.dispatch({
        actionType: todo.id ? actionTypes.UPDATE_TODO : actionTypes.CREATE_TODO,
        todo: savedTodo
    });
}
```